# New-AzureRmEventGridSubscription reports success but Get-AzureRmEventGridSubscription fails

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I am creating two Azure function triggers when blob storage is updated. When I run the command it reports no failure, but if I do the Get-AzureRmEventSubscription command, it only shows one of the newly created triggers.

```
$azureFunctionNames = @("Function1", "Function2")
foreach ($azureFunctionName in $azureFunctionNames ) {
New-AzureRmEventGridSubscription -EventSubscriptionName $azureFunctionName -Endpoint $Endpointurl -ResourceId $storageId -EndpointType "WebHook" -IncludedEventType "Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated"
}
```

No failures are reported, but when I do a Get-AzureRmEventGridSubscription it only shows one of the two. The most perplexing part is I can see them both in the portal.

Comment: Add the complete command to your question will be helpful.

Comment: Can you provide the calls that you are making and the errors?